# How to update a foreignkey instance model value on import

Tags: django-import-export

I've got 2 models :

```
class Fund(LabsManagerBudgetMixin, ActiveDateMixin): 
    ref= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Reference'))
    start_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Start Date'))
    end_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('End Date'))
    
class Fund_Item(LabsManagerBudgetMixin, CachedModelMixin):
    amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Amount'), default=0, null=True)
    type=models.ForeignKey(Cost_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Type'))
    fund=models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Related Fund'))
```

the mixins add some other fields, methods, managers ....

For the second one (Fund_Item) the admin extends "ImportExportModelAdmin" and the ressource class (see below) identify the foreignkey in the before_import_row method from a ref field.

The csv from which I update FundItem objects contains the 'ref', 'start_date', 'end'date' of the foreingkey linked object Fund.

I would like to update alongside the Fund_Item object the value dates of the foreign objects Fund.

I would point it as a value to update if needed at the file upload and parsing, and update the value on the import finalisation.

The [doc states](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget): "*…using a [`ForeignKeyWidget`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget) has the advantage that it can not only be used for exporting, but also importing data with foreign key relationships.*"

But I'm only able to update the foreingkey of the current model and not the foreign model attributes.

I don't know where to start digging which method to override. Could point me out a direction?

```
class FundItemAdminResource(labResource, SkipErrorRessource):
    fund=FundField(
        column_name=_('Ref'),
        attribute='fund', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Fund, 'ref'), 
        readonly=False
    )
    type=Field(
        column_name=_('type'),
        attribute='type', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Cost_Type, 'short_name'), 
        readonly=False
    )

    start_date=FundField(
        column_name=_('Start Date'),
        attribute='fund', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Fund, 'start_date'), 
        readonly=False
    )
    end_date=FundField(
        column_name=_('End Date'),
        attribute='fund', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Fund, 'end_date'),
        readonly=False
    )
    
    amount=FundItemField(
        column_name=_('Budget'),
        attribute='amount', 
        widget=widgets.DecimalWidget(),
        readonly=False
    )
            
        
    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        query = Q(amount__gte=-1)

        refI = row.get('Ref', None)
        if refI is not None:
            query = query & Q(fund__ref=refI)
            
        typeC = row.get('type', None)
        if typeC is not None:
            query = query & Q(type__short_name=typeC)            
        
        fu = Fund_Item.objects.filter(query)
        if fu is not None and fu.count()==1:
            row["id"] = fu.first().pk
        else:
            row["id"] = None
        return fu
        
    class Meta:
        """Metaclass"""
        model = Fund_Item
        skip_unchanged = True
        clean_model_instances = False
        exclude = [ '' ]
        export_order=[
                      'start_date',
                      'end_date',
                      'type',
                      'fund',
                      'amount',
                      ]
```

I've tryeid to tweak clean and save method of a custom field, but I land on issues or error each time

```
class FundField(Field):
     def clean(self, data, **kwargs):
        query = Q(amount__gte=-1)

        refI = data.get('Ref', None)
        if refI is not None:
            query = query & Q(ref=refI)
        
        fu = Fund.objects.filter(query).first()
        return fu

class FundDateField(FundField):
    def clean(self, data, **kwargs):        
        fu = super(FundField, self).clean(data, **kwargs)
        return getattr(fu, self.widget.field, None)
    
    def save(self, obj, data, is_m2m=False, **kwargs):
        # self.attribute=self.attribute+"__"+self.widget.field
        super(FundField, self).save(obj, data, is_m2m, **kwargs)
```

for the resource field defined as :

```
start_date=FundDateField(
        column_name=_('Start Date'),
        attribute='fund', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Fund, 'start_date'), 
        readonly=False
    )
```

---

[Edit]

I've use the clues from matthew below, I've implemented a custom Field which handle the column check and save from the clean method

```
class FundDateField(FundField):
    def clean(self, data, **kwargs):   
        fu = super().clean(data, **kwargs)
        field = self.widget.field
        attr =getattr(fu, field, None)
        nAttr=data.get(self.column_name)
        if attr!=nAttr:
            setattr(fu, field, nAttr)
            fu.save()
        print(" - fu : "+str(fu))
        
        return fu
```

and apply it to the resource date fields

```
start_date=FundDateField(
        column_name=_('Start Date'),
        attribute='fund', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Fund, 'start_date'), 
        readonly=False
    )
    end_date=FundDateField(
        column_name=_('End Date'),
        attribute='fund', 
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Fund, 'end_date'),
        readonly=False
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to update alongside the Fund_Item object the value dates of the foreign objects Fund.

It sounds like this is the core issue.  You would like to update the `Fund` instance with fields from the import.  The `Fund` has FK relationship to `Fund_Item` (which is the base model being imported).

The simplest way to achieve this would be to create a custom `ForeignKeyWidget` and add logic to the `clean()` method.

```py
class FundForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):

    def clean(self, value, row=None, **kwargs):
        # this will return the Fund instance (if it exists)
        # fund.ref will be used as the lookup field
        # (exception will be thrown if not exists)
        fund = super().clean(value)

        # add your own error checking here as required
        start_date = parse_datetime(row["Start Date"])
        fund.start_date = start_date

        end_date = parse_datetime(row["End Date"])
        fund.end_date = end_date

        fund.save()

        return fund
```

Then you don't need to declare 'Start Date', 'End Date' as separate fields, you can create one field for the FK reference:

```py
class FundItemAdminResource(labResource, SkipErrorRessource):
    # This defines that 'ref' will be used as the field to lookup Fund
    fund=FundField(
        column_name=_('Ref'),
        attribute='fund', 
        widget=FundForeignKeyWidget(Fund, 'ref'), 
    )
```

You could also use `before_import_row()` or `after_import_row()`:

```py
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        fund = Fund.objects.get(ref=row["ref")
        fund.start_date = parse_datetime(row["Start Date"])
        fund.end_date = parse_datetime(row["End Date"])
        fund.save()
```

Also, I don't know what's going on in your `before_import_row()` method.  It looks like you're trying to load a `Fund_Item` based on values in the import.  Don't forget that import-export will handle this for you.  You need to declare the lookup rows in `import_id_fields` ([docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#create-or-update-model-instances)).  So it might look something like:

```py
    import_id_fields = ('fund', 'type')
```

It is well worth setting a debugger and stepping through so you can see exactly what is going on.  This will save a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, it puts me on the track.
Actually, the clean method of th widget is not called at all during the process.
But the clean method of field is!

[edit] Don't know how to add a more detail answer in stackoverflow! should I edit the question?

Comment: best to use the debugger to figure out what's going on if you can

Comment: You mean smthing like pdb? Currently I manage the debug with the logger/print but it's rather fastidious

Comment: you can download and use a free version of PyCharm

Comment: thks, Actually I'm using vscode, and I dev from a debian VM (without GUI) dedicated to django; and i use several computer for coding, and i can't install python + package +venv in every machine (+git+docker+....).
I suppose pyCharm (that I've never used) debug the same way? i would love some fancy remote debugger btw.